# getJson not working on webhosting

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, getjson

I have a slight problem. I am connecting to a web service which provides JSON results and trying to parse the results. The code is working fine on my localhost (wamp server) but code doesn't run on any of the web hosting accounts I tried. 
Here is the url providing JSON

```
http://mohamedbadr.com/webservice/list.php
```

And here is my file which is trying to fetch results:

```
http://contestlancer.com/web/getList.php
```

Here is the code of the Getlist file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hotel Promotion List</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getList()
{
var i=0;

var ntable="<table><thead><tr><th>Image</th><th>Name</th><th>Rating</th><th>Highlights</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
$.getJSON("http://mohamedbadr.com/webservice/list.php", function(data){
    $.each(data.promos, function(key, value) {

ntable+="<tr><td><a href='promotion.php?id="+value.promo.id+"'><img src='"+value.promo.image+"' height='100' width='150'/></a></td><td><a href='promotion.php?id="+value.promo.id+"'>"+value.promo.name+"</a></td><td> "+value.promo.stars+"</td><td> "+value.promo.highlights+"</td></tr>";       
});

ntable+="</tbody></table>";
    $("#content").html(ntable);
});


}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="getList()">
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="content"></div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Most probably the url is not being opened what is the solution to this? Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you checked for appropriate [CORS](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) headers? If they are not set, you wont be able to get a response from a different domain ...

Comment: @Sirko sorry I am totally new to json what part of code do I need to change?

Comment: There is nothing you can change, unless you own the site, you get the json from. They have to set an additional header for cross origin requests to work. See the linked Wikipedia entry.

Comment: I own the site where I am getting json from @Sirko so please tell me what do I add there

Comment: See http://enable-cors.org/ for your servers setup procedure.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because you are making a cross domain request. Domain A to Domain B.

Try adding this to `http://mohamedbadr.com/webservice/list.php` before any output is printed.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://contestlancer.com');
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Looks like the problem to me. Will come back to you after adding this line :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Nadh, this is due to a cross-domain request. More info @ [HTTP Access Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control). Understanding [Same Origin Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules).

Since you are using jQuery getJson(), you may alternatively try this approach

```
var url =  "http://mohamedbadr.com/webservice/list.php";
$.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(data) {
    ... Success Logic here...
});
```

The `?callback=?` at the end of the url, will convert your request to a JSONP. And if you remove it, this will be a plain Ajax call.

Understanding [JSONP](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/)

-- Arvind.